# Auditing time while waiting for tasks

Tags: work-time, time-management

Sometimes it seem that my day just go by and i am  unable to justify myself, where i spend and doing what. I am in a new role, where i am waiting for a external company to provide design and i can start working on it, meanwhile i explore and do what is told to me but again i want to audit my time and how i spend it, what i learned because if a manager asks me and I can tell.Sometimes i stray to other websites such as news or amazon but how can i manage and audit my time, especially when i got nothing to work on?

Answer (score 1):

There is always something to be doing. If you have capacity, you can always ask your colleagues if they need you to do anything.

Regarding auditing your time, build yourself a work log (use MS Access, or SQL with an interface, or just Excel to get started). This will allow you to record what tasks came in on whaty day and at what time, you can filter to show active tasks, and filter to show completed tasks to show your boss.

Comment: i started using focus booster and it does help with pomodoro technique.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to be proactive and talk to your boss, tell them you spend a lot of time waiting and wondering if there is anything you could help you co-workersor learn a new skill.